# Sending mails from Heroku using Scheduler (CRON)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, cron, actionmailer, scheduler

I have my app at Heroku (in Rails 3.1). When I set the ActionMailer for sending emails, I got the error `Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`.

I fixed it this way (ApplicationController):

```
  before_filter :mailer_set_url_options

  def mailer_set_url_options
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
  end
```

It works fine. But now I need to send a couple e-mail every day at midnight, so I put this line into the task in **scheduler.rake**:

```
Mailer.notif_invoice(@inv_user, @invoice.id).deliver
```

And I got this error:

```
`Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`
```

I am getting this error only in a moment, when I want to send a e-mails by `Scheduler`.

Could you give me a tips, how to fix it?

I tried to add this line into my task:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
```

but I got the error

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `request' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the reason your code isn't working is down to the fact that you are relying on request to figure out the domain for the email, but if you're firing the mail directly, you don't have a request to play with...

Therefore, try putting this into your configure block in your appropriate environment file (for instance config/production.rb)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your_domain' }
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

You need to set the domain that the emails will need to link back to somewhere in your code, but this can be an environment variable or similar, just not something that relies on request.